# Open jquery ui tooltip programmatically with custom content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip, jquery-widgets

I want to programmatically open a jquery ui tooltip (not hover) with a custom content tooltip like this [here](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content).  Is there any way to do this ?

```
$('.links').tooltip({
  content: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var extra = $this.text();
    var lowertext = "<div class ='tooltiptext'>Find out more about " + extra + "</div>"
    return lowertext;
  }
  $('.links').tooltip("open");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to trigger the `mouseover()` event after initializing the tooltip:

```
$('.links').tooltip().mouseover();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works like you tried it, but your problem are your typos, you forgot some `;`and brackets also. try like this:

```
    $('.links').tooltip( {
                    content: function () { 
                        var lowertext = "<div class='tooltiptext'>Find out more about " + $(this).text() + "</div>";
                        return lowertext;
                    }
    });
    $('.links').tooltip('open');
```

Comment: I fixed the typos however, when I run the code it never goes in the content function....and nothing happends

Comment: could you provide some updated code and some html-structure in your question? the example code i provided works in my test.